# How to choose a random text in visual basic?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vba, text, random

I made own box from buttons, which have text 0 to `getupperbound(1)` and now I would like to choose one of them , randomly .

Comment: Please add more background to your question. What is it exactly you want to achieve? What have you tried to reach that goal? Where have you failed? It would help if you'd add your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

To get a random integer between two numbers (Min and Max, including) do something like this:

```
Function GetRandomNumber(ByVal Min As Integer, ByVal Max As Integer) As Integer
    Randomize
    GetRandomNumber = Int(Rnd * (Max - Min + 1) + Min)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure that the buttons have the same name, and an index property.
Then, you'll need to randomize a button index, and then use it on the button array.

```
Dim index as Integer
Randomize
index = Round(Rnd*getupperbound(1)) ' a random index
'Do something with Button(index)
index = Round(Rnd*getupperbound(1)) 'Another random index
'Do something with Button(index)
```